# Getting a org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: Authors after using @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to persist collection of string for an Entity. To be more specific here is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHOR")
public class Author{
   //Other fields associated with author
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name = "AUTHOR_PHONE_NUMBER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
   @Column(name="phone_number")
   private Set<String> phoneNumbers;

  //Constructors
  //Getters & Setters

}
```

However, when I build and run the code, I am getting following exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: AUTHOR for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(phone_number)]
```

I am seeing many questions similar to this on this platform but all those involve OneToMany mapping to persist collections.

Answer (score 0):

The list phoneNumbers should be ***@OneToMany***, ***@ManyToMany*** (this depends from AUTHOR_PHONE_NUMBER table) annotation, replacing @CollectionTable.

the configuration must be same with ***@JoinColumn*** annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I don't want to create a new mapping class for AUTHOR_PHONE_NUMBER and want to go ahead with '@ElementCollection' implementation. Also, want to know why the MappingException shows up with this implementation.